# I have this join sql statement but i can't seem to get the output that I want

Tags: sql, join

```
SELECT * FROM tblcheck as ch 
INNER JOIN 
rooms as r on ch.room_id = r.room_id
INNER JOIN
roomtype as c on c.RoomType_id = r.RoomType_id
INNER JOIN
guest as g on g.room_id = ch.room_id
```

the output I want is to display this

```
Guest Name || Room Name || Roomtype || Check-in Date and Time
```

but I have an error in the guest name. It displays everyone in the Guest Table :( Please help me

Comment: Remove the `guest` table from the `JOIN` if you don't want that information.

Comment: Really bad description of the question I think. Put the data you get now and the data you want to get. Also show us the structure of table.

Answer (score 0):

Would be easier to help if we knew the table structure. As far the returned columns you can select like the below:

```
SELECT
    g.name
   ,r.name
   ,r.roomtype
   ,ch.checkInDate
   ,ch.time
FROM
    tblcheck as ch 
INNER JOIN 
    rooms as r on ch.room_id = r.room_id
INNER JOIN
    roomtype as c on c.RoomType_id = r.RoomType_id
INNER JOIN
    guest as g on g.room_id = ch.room_id
```